# Как настроить квоты Dovecot

Tags: centos, vps, dovecot

Есть *VPS* под *CentOS 7*, почта на *Dovecot+Exim*. На нем несколько доменов с почтовыми ящиками.

Задача: настроить ограничения (квоты) на размер почтового ящика таким образом, чтобы они реально ограничивали объем почты в ящике и чтобы разным пользователям можно было задать разные квоты.

Следуя руководствам http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Quota и http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Quota/Configuration конфиги написаны следующим образом:

```
cat /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf
mail_privileged_group = mail
mail_access_groups = mail
mail_location = maildir:%h/mail/%d/%n
pop3_uidl_format = %08Xu%08Xv
mail_plugins = $mail_plugins quota
```

---

```
cat /etc/dovecot/conf.d/20-imap.conf
##
## IMAP specific settings
##

protocol imap {
mail_plugins = $mail_plugins autocreate imap_quota
#включается оповещение о квоте  по IMAP - в Roundcube появляется красивая диаграмма, показывающая, насколько заполнен почтовый ящик
}

plugin {
  autocreate = Trash
  autocreate2 = Spam
  autocreate3 = Sent
  autocreate4 = Drafts
  #autocreate5 = Custom
  autosubscribe = Trash
  autosubscribe2 = Spam
  autosubscribe3 = Sent
  autosubscribe4 = Drafts
  #autosubscribe5 = Custom
}
```

---

```
cat /etc/dovecot/conf.d/90-quota.conf
plugin {
    quota_grace = 10%%
    # 10% is the default
    quota_status_success = DUNNO
    quota_status_nouser = DUNNO
    quota_status_overquota = "552 5.2.2 Mailbox is full"
    quota = maildir:User quota

    #задается квота для всех
    quota_rule = *:storage=700MB

    #задается квота для отдельного e-mail
    quota_rule2 = email@server.ru:storage=+200MB

    quota_rule3 = Trash:storage=+100M
    quota_rule4 = Spam:storage=+100M
    }
```

Проблемы:

- ограничения не работают - в почтовый ящик можно положить сколько угодно почты;
- По крайней мере, судя по показаниям в Roundcube, срабатывает только строчка, задающая квоту для всех. Строчка, задающая квоты для отдельного e-mail не срабатывает.

В логах dovecot ошибок нет

Comment: Дублированный вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/486597/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%8f%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-dovecot?s=2|0.4720

Comment: @Monoceros, нет, это уже конкретизация. а тот вопрос автору лучше было бы удалить, потому что простой пересказ документации — дело малоосмысленное.